# IntelliJ IDEA database client doesn't connect with h2

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, h2

I want to use Intellij IDEA Database Client for H2 Console. But, the Client never read my h2 db schema.

I tried to use in-memory, embedded, and remote. In case of in-memory and embedded, database client connect with h2 successfully, but cannot read schema. When I tried to connect my h2 db using remote, only intelliJ IDEA throw connection error. H2 console and telnet can connect to the port! I thought it was because of WSL, but it’s not. Because my windows browser can connect with h2. What can I do?

this is codes and error message.

```yaml
// application-local.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:local;
      username: sa
      password: 
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

```java
// H2ServerConfiguration.java
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class H2ServerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari")
  public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9093", "-ifNotExists").start();
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
}
```

[Datasource properties & error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePIDM.png)

Comment: It isn't related to your question, but you should never use `-tcpAllowOthers` with `-ifNotExists` together, combination of these settings creates a remote security hole on your system.

Comment: Oh, I was missing important thing. It's all because I just copied someone else's code :(
I have to study more. thx.